# Varchar conversions and comparisons confusion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I read the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58357450/how-does-implicit-conversion-work-with-comparisons-of-varchar-representati) question and I have a similar problem. While the question was answered I didn't see a solution that would work for me.

In my case I ran the following code:

```
if '98' >='140'
print True
else
print False;
```

After reading the answer to the other question, I now understand why it returned True. What I am looking for is how to compare the two values correctly.

The first value would be data stored in a `varchar()` field, while the comparison value is '140'. (These represent blood pressures in this instance, but the source table has other data in it, hence the `varchar` data type)

I tried to remove the quote marks from 140 and it performed as expected in my test. However when ran against the production data, I got an error when converting 20.38 to int. I've tried converting to different data types but can't find one to handle all the possibilities.

Here is the code from my production file:

```
    ,"CPTCode" =
        Case 
        when oh.NAME = 'BP SYSTOLIC' and convert(int,ro.obsvalue) <= '140' then '3075F' --swapped obsvalue range with 3074F  3-30-2020
        when oh.NAME = 'BP SYSTOLIC' and convert(int,ro.obsvalue) < '130'  then '3074F'
        when oh.NAME = 'BP SYSTOLIC'and convert(int,ro.obsvalue) >= '140' then '3077F'
        when oh.NAME = 'BP DIASTOLIC' and convert(int,ro.obsvalue) < '80' then '3078F'
        when oh.NAME = 'BP DIASTOLIC' and (convert(int,ro.obsvalue) > '79' and convert(int,ro.obsvalue) <= '89') then '3079F'
        when oh.NAME = 'BP DIASTOLIC' and convert(int,ro.obsvalue) >= '90' then '3080F'
    Else
        #CodeMap.CPTCode    
    End
```

This was brought to my attention when there was a value of 98 for the BP SYSTOLIC entry that was coded with 3077F.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: I'm using SQL 2014

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main problem with your query is the order of the `case` expression. The database stops when it meets the first matching condition, so you have to be careful about the order o range comparisons.

Your first case catches all values below 140, so the second condition (values below 130) is never met. You would need to swap these:

```
    when oh.NAME = 'BP SYSTOLIC' and convert(int,ro.obsvalue) < 130  then '3074F'
    when oh.NAME = 'BP SYSTOLIC' and convert(int,ro.obsvalue) <= 140 then '3075F' 
    when oh.NAME = 'BP SYSTOLIC'and convert(int,ro.obsvalue) >= 140 then '3077F'
```

Note: I removed the single quotes around the litteral numbers - since that's what they are (numbers), they should be written as such.

Comment: I tried this and removed the quotes, but I still received the error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '20.38' to data type int." The problem is the ro.obsvalue field could contain text or integers or decimals.

Comment: @Tmartin: actually, I think you might need to combine the solution by David Browne (to avoid the conversion error) and mine (for the sequence in the `case` expressions)...

Comment: I should have stated in my question that we are on SQL 2014, so I'm exploring using the TRY_CONVERT() function. I'll edit my original question to include the version information for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The correct conversion, assuming the `obsvalue` is a string of the form ######.##, would be

```
   ,"CPTCode" =
        Case 
        when oh.NAME = 'BP DIASTOLIC' and convert(decimal(10,2),ro.obsvalue) < 80 then '3078F'
        when oh.NAME = 'BP SYSTOLIC' and convert(decimal(10,2),ro.obsvalue) < 130  then '3074F'
        when oh.NAME = 'BP SYSTOLIC' and convert(decimal(10,2),ro.obsvalue) <= 140 then '3075F' --swapped obsvalue range with 3074F  3-30-2020
        when oh.NAME = 'BP SYSTOLIC'and convert(decimal(10,2),ro.obsvalue) >= 140 and convert(decimal(10,2),ro.obsvalue) <= 79) then '3077F'
        when oh.NAME = 'BP DIASTOLIC' and (convert(decimal(10,2),ro.obsvalue) > 79 and convert(decimal(10,2),ro.obsvalue) <= 89) then '3079F'
        when oh.NAME = 'BP DIASTOLIC' and convert(decimal(10,2),ro.obsvalue) >= 90 then '3080F'
    Else
        #CodeMap.CPTCode    
    End
```

Comment: I just added a comment to the other answer. The obsvalue could contain data in text, integer or decimal (xx.xx) form. Though this might be closer. I'll give it  try.

Answer (score 0):

Just break up the query into 2 part. 
In the first use isNumeric(ro.obsvalue) in the WHERE clause and then convert the data. In the second part you use 3077F

```
with ro_obsvalue(key, value) as (
select key, convert(int, value)
  from ro 
 where isnumeric(value)=1
union all
select key, 98
 from ro
 where value = '3077F'
)
select 
  from ro_obsvalue ...
```